# remain text field data after window message

Tags: php, javascript, forms

When the user entered wrong or empty field value and the window message prompts out, how do I retain the data in the text fields that the user had entered after the window message?

```
<?php if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Fields marked with an asterisk are required");
        history.back();
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to either use ajax to stop the page from changing at all. Or instead of doing a javascript inside your if, re-print the whole form with the answers the user had given as the default value.  You shouldn't be using history.back() for what you're trying to do, at all.

Comment: if I remove the history.back(), it will go to a blank page. Can you show me how to not letting the page load? I'm new to programming.

Comment: Absolutely, I can help you with that. I just need to see a little bit more of your code to understand the whole context of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three solutions

1. Client-side HTML5: add `required` attribute to each required element (see the support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=required))
2. Client-side javascript see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182755/stop-submit-with-empty-input-values)
3. Server-side php (as you do): store the POST values into SESSION and set them as values to those elements